# How can I add LINQ support to my library?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to add LINQ support to my library, so I can use SQL like queries on it like you can with `System.Xml`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Implementing LINQ simply means implementing the methods LINQ expects to be there, such as `Where` or `Select`, with the correct signatures. Despite common perception, you do not have to implement the `IEnumerable` interface for your class to support LINQ. However, implementing `IEnumerable` will *automatically* get you the entire set of LINQ methods on the `Enumerable` class almost for free -- you only have to implement `GetEnumerator` and an `IEnumerator` class.

There are a couple of examples on how to implement `IEnumerable` on my blog, in this post about [the Iterator pattern](http://blog.kutulu.org/2012/05/practical-patterns-2-iterators.html).

However, if it doesn't make sense for your class to be enumerable, you don't need to do so. You just need to implement the appropriate LINQ methods directly. LINQ doesn't actually care how the methods get defined, so long as the C# compiles. That is, if you write:

```
from p in myPlist where p.Thing == "Thing" select p;
```

the C# compiler translates this into:

```
mpPlist.Where(p => p.Thing == "Thing").Select(p => p);
```

As long as that compiles, LINQ will work. To see the correct signatures for the methods, look as the MSDN documentation's [list of LINQ query methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397896.aspx). For example (assume that your `PList` was a list of `PListItem`s):

```
public class PList
{
  public IEnumerable<PListItem> Where(Func<PListItem, bool> predicate)
  {
    foreach (var item in this.items)
    {
      if (predicate(item)) 
      {
        yield return item;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

While implementing LINQ directly in this manner gives you a lot more control over how it behaves, it's a *lot* more work to get it right, and you need to understand the implications of your return values, and chaining LINQ calls, etc. In general, if you can get away with making your class implement `IEnumerable` and let C# do all the work for you, things go much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Since LINQ to objects works with any class that inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`, implementing that interface in your class would be enough.

The following link explains on how to implement the IEnumerable interface (although it does not mention LINQ, it will work):
http://codebetter.com/davidhayden/2005/03/08/implementing-ienumerable-and-ienumerator-on-your-custom-objects/

Answer (score 1):

You must implement IEnumerable first.
Read that first - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx