# Linq-Connection for data structure

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures

I recently designed a data structure similar to 'Queue' and 'Stack' for a special purpose, with a fixed maximum number of objects in it and when it is full and inserted, the first inserted object drops out.

The Code:

```
public class AssemblyLine<T>
{      

    private long length;
    public long Length { get { return this.length; } }

    private T[] data;
    private long Pointer = 0;

    private long count = 0;
    public long Count { get { return this.count; } }

    public void Insert(T obj)
    {

        this.Data[Pointer] = obj;
        this.Next();

        if (this.count < this.length)
            this.count++;

    }

    public T[] GetLastX(long x)
    {

        long p = this.Pointer;

        if (x > this.count)
            x = this.count;

        T[] result = new T[x];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {

            Previous();
            result[i] = Grab();

        }

        this.Pointer = p;
        return result;

    }

    public T[] GetFirstX(long x)
    {

        long p = this.Pointer;

        if (x > this.count)
            x = this.count;

        long gap = this.length - this.count;
        this.Pointer = (this.Pointer + gap) % this.length;

        T[] result = new T[x];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {

            result[i] = Grab();
            Next();

        }

        this.Pointer = p;
        return result;

    }

    public void Clear()
    {

        this.data = new T[this.length];
        this.count = 0;

    }

    private void Next()
    {

        this.Pointer++;

        if (this.Pointer > this.length - 1)
            this.Pointer = 0;

    }

    private void Previous()
    {

        this.Pointer--;

        if (this.Pointer < 0)
            this.Pointer = this.length - 1;

    }

    private T Grab()
    {

        return this.data[this.Pointer];

    }

    public AssemblyLine(long Length)
    {

        this.length = Length;
        this.data = new T[Length];

    }

}
```

Now I am curious if its possible to get that connected to Linq, providing something like this:

```
  AssemblyLine<int> myAssemblyLine = new AssemblyLine(100);

  // Insert some Stuff

  List<int> myList = myAssemblyLine.Where(i => i > 5).ToList();
```

Any idea someone?

Comment: Your `AssemblyLine` class with have to implement `IEnumerable`. Your better bet would be to derive your classes from `Queue<T>`, unless that's `sealed`.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` actually, for his use case.

Comment: Right. My comment was an end of the day, abut to walk out the door from work in 10 seconds, quick throw something up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all LINQ extension methods are declared on `IEnumerable<T>`, so as soon as your class implements that interface, you'll get it for free.

There are just couple methods that use non-generic `IEnumerable`, like `Cast` or `OfType`, but if you can get your class implement generic `IEnumerable<T>` it will be much better, because users won't have to call `Cast<T>` first, to get `IEnumerable<T>` and access all the other methods (as is right now the case for some legacy collections).

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement `IEnumerable<T>` for .Where(). See [Adding LINQ to my classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068580/adding-linq-to-my-classes).

Once you implement `IEnumerable<T>` and all required methods, you will have access to these methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.100).aspx