# C# get value of property inside inherited class

Tags: c#

I don't know the right words, so I will use a code example.

```
Class A {
    public MyList<MyModel> Models {
        get {
            // This won't work because it call's Models. How can I make this work??
            return Models.Load();
        };
    }
}

Class MyList<T> : List<T>{
    public List<T> Load(){
        return Something();
    }
}
```

This is the thing I want to do:

```
var context = new A();
context.Models.Where(...);
```

Comment: who inherits what class? The class A with a property inherits nothing.

Comment: You're going to have to find the right words.  It isn't clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: It does not inherit any class

Comment: If you are inheriting from List, you're almost certainly doing something wrong. Don't inherit from List; use composition instead.

Comment: The question is in the comments

Comment: We need to know what you want `Models` to be in order for us to tell you how to implement `Models`.

Comment: Consider creating [MCVE]. Currently, it isn't clear what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can give you is if you are looking to implement LINQ into your classes, someone made a post here
[Adding LINQ to my classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068580/adding-linq-to-my-classes)

If you're looking to use an index for your class, there's a link here

[Setting List items in C# without automatic setter/getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871172/setting-list-items-in-c-sharp-without-automatic-setter-getter)

But, unless you post an objective, and where you're hung up, there's not much we can help you with.

Answer (score 0):

Create a private field `private MyList<MyModel> _model`, initialze it, and return it in the `Models` property via `_model.Load()`.